# Why my program occupies 32KB and not 11200B (Valgrind's massif)

Tags: c, valgrind

The n-body program does this at the begining:

```
  real4 *pin  = (real4*)malloc(n * sizeof(real4));
  real4 *pout = (real4*)malloc(n * sizeof(real4));
  real3 *v    = (real3*)malloc(n * sizeof(real3));
  real3 *f    = (real3*)malloc(n * sizeof(real3));
```

the total size of this should be (if n = 100): 100*32 + 100*32 + 100*24 + 100*24 = 11200B but with Valgrind's massif I have this:

[image]

Comment: Which compiler are you using, and what flags did you specify for the compile?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm using gcc and I specified 100 iterations and 100 bodies

Comment: Your math seems a little suspicious. I get 11200, not 1120

Comment: @user3386109 true

Comment: Ok, now I have to wonder what all the colons represent. If 32K is the top of the Y-axis, then the colons seem to be at about 10K, which matches your expected memory usage.

Comment: @user3386109 probably yes, but why is # getting the top at the begining?

Comment: Try `n==1` and look at the _change_ in memory usage.  See if that is a expected.

Comment: Are you allocating your memory in the beginning of the program execution?

Comment: I'm pretty certain everything @user3386109 said is correct. That looks exactly right.

Comment: Do you use C standard library in your program? Did you include all the allocations the standard library does in your calculations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not fammilliar with `massif`, but when talking about heap memory, there are two numbers that are interesting, how much memory has the allocator requested from the OS, and how much has the allocator given to your program through `malloc()`. If your program has requested ~10K of bytes, it is reasonable to think that the allocator may have requested a round number like 32K from the OS. The allocator typically request memory in large blocks from the OS since kernel calls are slow. (and a few other reasons)

So I would guess that the 32K that you are seeing, is what the allocator has aquired from the OS, ready to be given to your program through any additional `malloc()` that may happen.